# How do I check if the playing song is (not) in English?

Tags: spotify-app, spotify-desktop

Is it possible to get the language of the currently playing song in spotify?

```
models.player.addEventListener('change', function(data)
{
    var track = data.track.name, artist = data.track.artists[0].name;
    var language = "?????";
});
```

Comment: I searched for "Spotify song language" and this was one of the first hits: http://www.quora.com/Spotify/Does-spotify-list-songs-by-a-language. It sounds like Spotify doesn't store anything about language metadata, so this is probably impossible. I can't say that surprises me too much. You *might* be able to find a third-party data source, but I'd even be unsure of that.